# Postscript Blue Book

Tags: postscript

There used to be a tutorial book on Postscript from Adobe referred to as the Blue Book. There was also a Green Book. I used to have them but I am now utterly unable to find them on the internet. What became of these, and would anybody know how to get PDFs? The Reference Manual for Postscript Level 3 is still currently available from Adobe.

Comment: I could find them easily enough with Google http://ruby.kyoto-wu.ac.jp/~konami/Documents/ps/bluebook.pdf and https://www.scribd.com/document/63878845/Postscript-Language-Program-Design-GREEN-BOOK.

Comment: What search terms did you use? These eluded me.

Comment: "PosScript Blue Book" and "PostScript Green Book" :-)

Answer (score 2):

PDF copies used to be available on Adobe's public PostScript Developer Partner website. This website is now defunct, but the site and its contents — [http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/sample/](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/sample/*) — are available on Internet Archive's [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/). The file links below are to the most recent mirrors I could find.

- **PostScript Language Tutorial & Cookbook** (“Blue Book”) — Adobe Systems Incorporated / Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Inc., 1985; ISBN 0-201-10179-3; Second printing: December 1985; PDF modification date 1994-11-14: [BlueBook.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822204111/http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/sample/BlueBook.zip) or on Internet Archive: [PostScript language tutorial and cookbook](https://archive.org/details/PSBlueBook)
- **PostScript Language Program Design** (“Green Book”) — Adobe Systems Incorporated / Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Inc., 1988; ISBN 0-201-14396-8; First printing: February 1988; PDF modification date 1994-11-14: [GreenBook.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106015211/http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/sample/GreenBook.zip) or on Internet Archive: [PostScript language program design](https://archive.org/details/PSGreenBook/page/n7/mode/2up)

Both archives contain all the code examples from their respective books.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Question, and in addition to the "Blue" and "Green" books as answered

"Red Book" is still offered direct from Adobe.
PostScript® LANGUAGE REFERENCE third edition
https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf

"Grey Book"
Portable Document Format Reference Manuals most versions including milestones
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.0.pdf
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.4.pdf

And "White Book"
Type 1 Font Format
https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/font-tech-notes/blob/main/pdfs/T1_SPEC.pdf

Other colours were used for other Adobe Documents but most others are out of date and thus no longer accessible.